# Bootstrap 3 1.5 column offset

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am trying to come up with a Bootstrap 3 grid layout where the top row has 4 columns and the bottom has 3 columns centered against the first like so...

[image]

I have looked at using offset but because they bottom row would need to use a left offset of 1.5 columns it isn't working.

Has anyone got a similar working example I can look at?

Comment: I don’t think that’s possible without doing any hacks. It’s simple math. You might want to create a new helper class for that. Should be fairly simple.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I made something similar for an org-chart like this:

HTML

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-3 box">
          Column
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-3 box">
          Column
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-3 box">
          Column
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-3 box">
          Column
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row center-boxes">
        <div class="col-md-3 col-md-push-1 box">
          Column
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-3 col-md-push-1 box">
          Column
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-3 col-md-push-1 box">
          Column
        </div>
    </div>
 </div>
```

CSS

```
  .container{
    background:#ccc;
  }

  .box{
    background: gray;
    height:50px;
    text-align:center;
    padding:15px;
    border:1px solid black;
  }

  .center-boxes div{
     margin:0 -4% 0 4%;
  }
```

*This only satisfies the desktop view, adjust accordingly to smaller devices until you end up with `col-xs-12` which at that point the offset (push) won't matter

And some @media query adjustments will be needed at 1024px and 991px with the `margin:0 -4% 0 4%;`

See the working demo [**here**](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/gPgWGG)

Comment: That works perfectly, thanks for contributing, it's saved me a massive headache!

Comment: my pleasure!. Glad I helped