# how to get div content in middle using bootstrap

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap

[image]I have 3 divs in a row, I need 3 divs should be aligned in the center.

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="center">
    <div class="col-sm-4" id="ph-container"></div>
    <div class="col-sm-4" id="do-container"></div>
    <div class="col-sm-4" id="water-temperature-container"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Use `text-center` instead of `center`.

Comment: It doesn't sound clear what you're asking, if you want the contents of your three divs to be centre aligned, then the answer provided by Praveen will work.

However, if you mean you want the three divs stacked ontop of each other, but centred on the page, then you'll need to remove the `col-sm-4` class, as this applies the float.

Comment: Okay, the code you're using will equally spread all three divs across the page, as that's what the Bootstrap classes do. What I think you should do instead, is use my answer provided...

Comment: Can you make a preview of [mcve]?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `text-center` instead of `center`.

```html
<div class="row">
  <div class="text-center">
    <div class="col-sm-4 col-sm-offset-1" id="ph-container"></div>
    <div class="col-sm-4" id="do-container"></div>
    <div class="col-sm-4" id="water-temperature-container"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Adding an offset will help you in making the view better.

Comment: im not getting div in center

Comment: What exactly are you expecting? Can you show an image?

Comment: @Swapna Looks like you need to show the full code to make it work.

Comment: Given the original question didn't have enough detail, this is correct answer according to what's been provided by the OP...

Comment: No it's not, the OP has provided enough information to visually understand what the expected result is, and it's not to centre the contents of the divs.

Comment: @Lee Yes, technically that happened after OP seeing and testing my answer and providing extra details. Until then this was right.

Comment: I'm just saying, it now makes your answer incorrect, that's all.

Comment: @Lee I can understand and I am changing it.

Answer (score 0):

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-offset-1 col-sm-3" id="ph-container"></div>
    <div class="col-sm-3" id="do-container"></div>
    <div class="col-sm-3" id="water-temperature-container"></div>
</div>
```

This makes the three divs slightly narrower, and pushes them from the left, making them appear in the centre of the page.

Bear in mind, by making the divs narrower, your graphs may not look correct, so you'll need to correct your styling to adapt into the new div sizes.

This might help you actually: [Bootstrap 3 1.5 column offset](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34571395/bootstrap-3-1-5-column-offset)

Comment: You could change the classes to `col-sm-3`, but you won't be able to push them by 1.5 grid positions... Try changing the offset to `col-sm-offset-1` or `col-sm-offset-2` and see what looks best. You could always override the style further in your own CSS.

Answer (score 0):

the total number of cols is 12, if you use 12 cols (4+4+4=12) it will be not in center cose they wil be take all with of parent block.
So you must use less cols

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-pull-1 col-sm-3" id="ph-container"></div>
    <div class="col-sm-3" id="do-container"></div>
    <div class="col-sm-3" id="water-temperature-container"></div>
</div>
```